# How to reset checked checkboxes on button click? (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, v-for

I am working on a custom search filter, where you can tick off checkboxes to better fit what you're looking for. (Working with Vue.js)

I also want to add a "clear" button, that gets rid of your all the ticks you made previously in the checkboxes. I have this for the button:

```
<button @click="clear">
     <span class="letterspace">クリアする</span>
</button>
```

and I'm not so sure how to define the method but I wrote it like so:

```
methods: {
    clear() {
      (this.selectLocations = []), (this.selectItems = []);
    }
}
```

this is the code I have for the checkboxes:

```
<div class="checkboxArea" v-show="showItem">
            <div id="checkboxes" v-for="(value, index) in items" :key="index">
              <label for="select" id="one">
                <input type="checkbox" :value="value" v-model="selectItems[index]" />
                {{ value }}
              </label>
           </div>
</div>
```

where `selectItems` is defined as an empty array in the data property:

```
data() {
    return {
      selectItems: []
    };
  },
```

Can somebody please help me figure this out?

Comment: Your 'clear' not working?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where `this.selectLocations` comes from because I don't see it in the template, but your function cannot work like that.

To reset your `selectItems`, you'd need to say:

```js
clear() {
  this.selectItems = [];
}
```

This will empty the selected items and deselect all checkboxes again.

Answer (score 1):

This is better approach imo.

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <button @click="clear()">Clear</button>
        <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
          <label>{{ item.label }}</label>
          <input v-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          items: [
            {
              label: 'Select 1',
              selected: false,
            },
            {
              label: 'Select 2',
              selected: false,
            },
          ],
          clear: () => {
            this.items.forEach((item) => (item.selected = false));
          },
        };
      },
    };
    </script>
```